# No duration on Hangup in freeswitch managed module

Tags: c#, freeswitch

I'm writing a managed module for FreeSwitch (it's in C# but I would imagine this applies to other languages) and I'm not getting a duration during the hangup process:

```
    public void Run(AppContext context)
    {
        context.Session.HangupFunction = () => Hangup(context.Session);
        HandleCall(context.Session);
    }

    private void Hangup(ManagedSession session)
    {
        Log.WriteLine(LogLevel.Info, "Hanging up");
        Log.WriteLine(LogLevel.Info, "Created time: " + session.Variables.CreatedTime);
        Log.WriteLine(LogLevel.Info, "Answered time: " + session.Variables.AnsweredTime);
        Log.WriteLine(LogLevel.Info, "Hangup time: " + session.Variables.HangupTime);
        Log.WriteLine(LogLevel.Info, "Duration: " + session.GetVariable("duration"));
    }
```

CreatedTime and AnsweredTime are both set.  But hangup time and duration are both empty.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Basically its a catch-22.  You are writing an app that is in the EXECUTE state and you have asked for a callback to run when it state changes to the HANGUP state but that callback has to be run while its still in your app which has to be BEFORE it changes from EXECUTE to HANGUP.  As soon as you exit your callback, the app will exit and then it will change to HANGUP and process all the other hangup stuff.  If we called your function afterwards, all the things you want to query will already have been torn down.

So you can basically assume the current time when your function runs is within a few microseconds of the real hangup time depending on how long you block in your function.   If you are trying to do anything that resembles CDR or call processing you should not be doing it there anyway.  Instead you can register an api_hangup_hook or or a state handler for CS_REPORTING where all of the data will be captured and exist in a separate logic flow from the applications.  This is by design.